# describe() returns "ERROR: UndefVarError: describe not defined"

Tags: dataframe, julia

I imported a table from a SQL database into a dataframe, and now I'm trying to get statistics about the dataframe via `describe()`. I also tried `head()`. Both return an error `"ERROR: UndefVarError: describe not defined"`.

I've added and imported the `DataFrames` package to resolve the issue, which didn't work.

This is how I imported the dataframe:

```
using Pkg

Pkg.add("ODBC")

Pkg.add("DataFrames")

using ODBC, DataFrames

db = ODBC.DSN(connection_string)

query = ODBC.query(db, "SELECT * FROM table")

df = DataFrame(query)

describe(df)
```

I am expecting a result similar to the `describe()` or `head()` Python functions. I would expect columns labels and the first few rows after running `head(df)`. I would expect min, max, avg, count, etc for each of the column labels after running `describe(df)`.

Comment: Have you also imported `Pandas.jl` or any other package that provides `describe` or `head`? In this case, you need to use fully-qualified names `DataFrames.describe` and `DataFrames.head`. This is not necessary in other situations.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised the Julia page I was reading from didn't mention that anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There is `first` instead of head. See the code below for a sample:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:5,b=6:10)
5×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 6     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 7     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 8     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 9     │
│ 5   │ 5     │ 10    │

julia> first(df,3)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 6     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 7     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 8     │

julia> describe(df)
2×8 DataFrame
│ Row │ variable │ mean    │ min   │ median  │ max   │ nunique │ nmissing │ eltype   │
│     │ Symbol   │ Float64 │ Int64 │ Float64 │ Int64 │ Nothing │ Nothing  │ DataType │
├─────┼──────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ a        │ 3.0     │ 1     │ 3.0     │ 5     │         │          │ Int64    │
│ 2   │ b        │ 8.0     │ 6     │ 8.0     │ 10    │         │          │ Int64    │
```

Comment: `head` is currently there, albeit deprecated. I do not think that the error OP gets is about `head` being deprecated.

Comment: @hckr note that by covering the method definition by another one he should not get `UndefVarError`. Anyway the fully qualified names you mentioned are useful indeed for name collision scenarios :-)

Comment: What I meant in my comment was a situation like `using Plots, GR; plot(rand(5))`. You will get an `UndefVarError` in this case and accompanied with a warning the first time you try to access `plot`.

Comment: I like your example. Although I just checked that this only happens when 2 packages are imported within a single `using` statement.

Comment: Not necessarily, try `using Plots; using GR; plot(rand(5))`. I believe unless you make a call to `plot` in your code before `using GR`, you will still get `UndefVarError`. So `using Plots; ...write as many statements that do not call plot;  using GR; plot` will still give you an `UndefVarError`. If you do call `plot` before that, however, `plot` without qualifier will point to `Plots.plot` and you will still need to qualify `plot` if you need to access `GR.plot`.